# Terminate a forked process in python when the parent process dies using prctl

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, fork

Using prctl functions, it is possible to send a SIGKILL to a forked process when its parent process dies. The C implementation of this will work with a simple addition of **prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGKILL)**  line after the forking of a process.
However, I tried to do the same thing in python; Even though the parent process finishes successfully (or I kill it with kill), the child keeps running. In the demo implementation below, the parent finish after a while, but the child process keeps running. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
def child():
    print 'Child Process created with ID: %d ' %os.getpid()
    while True: 
        print 'PROCESS ID: %d ' %os.getpid() 
        time.sleep(2)  

def parent():
    x = 0
    newpid = os.fork()
    if newpid > 0:
        libc.prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGKILL)
    child()
    else:
        print "Parent process running with ID:  %d " % os.getpid()
        while (x<5):
            print 'PROCESS ID: %d ' %os.getpid() 
            time.sleep(2)
            x+=1 
parent()
```